# Clamp gameobject to within borders while slowly following another along x and y

Tags: unity-game-engine, clamp, lerp

I am trying to make an air hockey game and I need to clamp the AI into a specific area whilst it follows the puck around the board when it's in its half. I thought the following code would work but I'm getting some weird behaviour from the paddle where it will either a) get stuck at y=minY on start of the level or b) it will seemingly phase between minY and maxY continuously.

```
public float speed = 0.075f;
public float minX = -3.7f, minY = 6.7f, maxX = 3.7f, maxY = 0.5f;

void Update () {
    transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(Mathf.Lerp(transform.position.x, _puck.transform.position.x, speed), minX, maxX), 
                                     Mathf.Clamp(Mathf.Lerp(transform.position.y, _puck.transform.position.y, speed), minY, maxY),
                                     transform.position.z);
}
```

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT**
I should add that if I only use the clamp on the y it works as expected, however it may clip out of the x over time if I don't clamp that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `minY` is greater than `maxY`.

I think you should invert them.

Answer (score 0):

Mathf.Clamp clamps a value between two numbers: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html

Mathf.Lerp interpolates between 2 values by a thrid one.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html

If I got the ideeas you want your AI to be locked in a specific area: minY, maxY, minX, maxX while it still follows the puck. So you should just clamp the position of the puck between those values.

```
void Update () {
transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(_puck.transform.position.x, minX, maxX), Mathf.Clamp(_puck.transform.position.y, minY, maxY),transform.position.z);}
```

Comment: The way my game works would, unfortunately, make this more of a hack than a solution.

Comment: What makes you desired behaviour different ? Do you want it to move slower to where the puck is?

Comment: I don't need to clamp the puck as it interacts perfectly with the tables colliders, however the computers paddle needs to only interact with half the table therefore I need to make sure it's y value, in this case, is clamped. If I don't also clamp the x, I get an overlap with the borders which is ugly. If I don't clamp anything the computer will just follow the puck around the entirety of the table which I don't want. But anyway, the issue was with my min and max y values being backwards. Silly mistake.